# One variable returns two seperate array

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am currently working on a script that extracts the last lines of a csv file. This last line contains the temperature. I want to add the temperature of file1 to the temperature of file2 to calculate the average temperature. This is the code so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');


var handler = function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var avgtemp = []
    var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
    var lastLine = lines.slice(-1)[0];
    var fields = lastLine.split(',');
    var humidity = fields.slice(-1)[0];
    var temperature = fields.slice(-2)[0]
    var doe = avgtemp.push(parseFloat(temperature))
    console.log(avgtemp)

}
fs.readFile('datafile1.csv', 'utf-8', handler)
fs.readFile('datafile2.csv', 'utf-8', handler)
```

Now when the console log returns the following:

```
[ 24.57083333333333 ]
[ 20.57083333333333 ]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[24.57083333333333, 20.57083333333333]
```

I have tried multiple things, but I can't get it right. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're setting `avgtemp` to an empty array each time you read a file. Either move it out of the handler function or a better option would be to return the values and then join the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two request aren't linked in any way and are asynchronous, you have to group the data manually once both files have been read.

I usually use `util.promisify()` to turn `fs.readFile()` from accepting a callback into it returning a promise, so I can use `Promise.all()` to create the array once both files have been read:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
var { promisify } = require( 'util' );

var readFile = promisify( fs.readFile );

Promise
    .all([
        readFile( 'datafile1.csv' ),
        readFile( 'datafile2.csv' )
    ])
    .then( files => files.map( data => {
        var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
        var lastLine = lines.slice(-1)[0];
        var fields = lastLine.split(',');
        var humidity = fields.slice(-1)[0];
        var temperature = fields.slice(-2)[0];
        return parseFloat( temperature );
    }))
    //  Temperatures should equal [24.57083333333333, 20.57083333333333]
    .then( temperatures => console.log( temperatures ))
    .catch( error => {
        //  Handle error.
        console.error( error );
    });
```

Comment: this looks nice, thank you! One problem: error: data.trim is not a function

Comment: @Douwef You might have to readd the `UTF-8` parameter to readFile() . Or maybe use toString()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
var avgtemp = []
```

You set your avgtemp to an empty array in both "readFile"s.

If you want it to store both, just modify your script like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
var avgtemp = []

var handler = function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
    var lastLine = lines.slice(-1)[0];
    var fields = lastLine.split(',');
    var humidity = fields.slice(-1)[0];
    var temperature = fields.slice(-2)[0]
    var doe = avgtemp.push(parseFloat(temperature))
    console.log(avgtemp)

}
fs.readFile('datafile1.csv', 'utf-8', handler)
fs.readFile('datafile2.csv', 'utf-8', handler)
```

Comment: But wich value in `avgtemp` is from wich request? Are you aware that the requests can resolve in a random order?

Comment: I did that, but it returns: 
[20.34]
[20.34, 21.45]

If I put the console.log(avgtemp) out of the function it will return: [ ]. 

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You have to define array outside the function.
`var avgtemp = []` should be at global level rather than inside the function